# field access for lists of objects in a class via morphia in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, entity, field, morphia

I have some problems while implementing filters in mongodb using morphia POJO mapper.

In my class (for example `SampleClass`), when i try to access the fields of  an `@Entity` class (in our case it's `Person`), I find the field access works fine, using dot notation for general fields like int, string, maps or direct embedded objects.

The issue is I could not understand how it works for the case of a "List of Objects" referenced in the `Person` class. (Assume here, a person can have many addresses, so this `Person` class has a field `addresses` which holds a list of `Address` objects)

```
@Entity
Class Person
{
    String name;
    int age;
    String type;
    private Map<String, String> personalInfo= new HashMap<String, String>();
    @Reference
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>;
}

@Entity
Class Address
{
    String streetName;
    int doorNo;
}
```

For example, I want to apply a filter on `streetName` of the `Address` object which is in the `addresses` List

```
public class SampleClass
{  
    private Datastore ds;
    Query<Node>              query;
    CriteriaContainer        container;

    // connections params etc....
    public List<Person> sampleMethod()
    {
        query = ds.find( Person.class ).field( "type" ).equal( "GOOD");                              

        container.add( query.criteria( "name" ).containsIgnoreCase("jo" ));   
        // general String field in the Person Class ---- OKAY, Work's Fine

        container.add( query.criteria( "personalInfo.telephone" ).containsIgnoreCase( "458" ) ); 
        // Map field in the Person Class, accessing telephone key value in the map --- OKAY, Work's Fine

        container.add( query.criteria( "addresses.streetname").containsIgnoreCase( "mainstreet" ) ); 
        // List of address object in the Person Class, name of the field is 'addresses'
        // ----NOT OKAY   ????????? -- Here is the problem it returns nothing, even though some value exists

        return readTopography( query.asList() );
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong while accessing the objects in a list?

Answer (score 5):

"addresses" field is a @Reference we cannot use "addresses.name" as a field in a criteria. It should be a criteria where addresses field is in a  "List< Key< Address > >" :

```
    Query<Person> personQuery = ds.createQuery(Person.class);
    Query<Address> addressQuery = ds.createQuery(Address.class);
    addressQuery.criteria("streetName").containsIgnoreCase("mainstreet");
    container.add(personQuery.criteria("addresses").in(addressQuery.asKeyList()));

    System.out.println(personQuery.asList());
```

regards,
sadish

Answer (score 1):

Your query you actually try would query an subdocument `addresses` with the field `streetname`. So you will only get documents which have addresses as a concrete address not a list of addresses. To match all Persons containing at least one address matching use `$elemMatch` http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray .
But I'm not sure If Morphia is able to perform such queries, with your schema at all. Keep in mind that your actual Document isn't containing those addresses embedded, instead it contains only dbrefs http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References . So if morphia isn't smart enough to convert your query it will not succeed, as mongoDB doesn't know DBRefs at all (as this is only some driver convention).

So for the case morphia doesn't offer this functionality you need to query different. At first you need to query your Addresses collection for addresses matching your condition. Collect those ObjectIds and use them with `$elemMatch` and `$in` in your Person Collection query, to filter out all persons not having such an address, along with your further filter options. You need to keep in mind that you don't have some relational System which does the joining for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have found the solution. i will post it here

Comment: I have a doubt in this problem; if i make this field as **@Transient**                                                      **@Reference**                                               List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>; --> then can i apply the same solution? I find an issue that it could nt find the attribute addresses, because it is transient (nt saved in db). So how can we play with fields like this ? it has nt been saved, but i want to resolve a query using this field. any idea regarding this ?  thanks!

Comment: Everything you store as transient has to be considered of information only needed temporaly ( and mostly of no big value). So basically what you do with transient fields is to offer some computed values as runtime, out of other non transient fields. If you need such information to query on, theres no way around from storing them in mongo.  
Why do you want that to be transient and not persisted, whats your business logic behind it?
Why do you need the Person/Address connection only at runtime and not persisted?

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like tyop for me `container.add( query.criteria( "addresses.streetname").containsIgnoreCase( "mainstreet" ) );`.

I think `streetname` needs to be changed to `streetName`.

I have been using morphia for a year now. AFAIK, `container.add( query.criteria( "addresses.streetName").containsIgnoreCase( "mainstreet" ) );` should work fine.